# Gradient of a function evaluated over a batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gradient

I want to use Tensorflow to calculate the gradients of a function. However, if I use the `tf.gradients` function, it returns a single list of gradients. How to return a list for each point of the batch?

```py
# in a tensorflow graph I have the following code
tf_x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,N_in), name='x')
tf_net #... conveniently defined neural network
tf_y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,1), name='y')

tf_cost = (tf_net(tf_x) - tf_y)**2  # this should have length N_samples because I did not apply a tf.reduce_mean

tf_cost_gradients = tf.gradients(tf_cost,tf_net.trainable_weights)
```

If we run it in a tensorflow session,

```py
# suppose myx = np.random.randn(N_samples,N_in) and myy conveniently chosen
feed = {tf_x:myx, tx_y:myy}
sess.run(tf_cost_gradients,feed)
```

I get only one list, and not a list for each sample as I would like. I can use

```py
for i in len(myx):
    feed = {tf_x:myx[i], tx_y:myy[i]}
    sess.run(tf_cost_gradients,feed)
```

but this is extremely slow! What can I do? Thank you

Comment: The gradient of the function over a batch is indeed a vector in your case. If you intend to calculate the gradient of the function w.r.t each sample, then it is called stochastic gradient descent and you need to do it one by one just as shown in your code.

Comment: @danyfang, No, SGD is when you compute and apply grads wrt the part of the data. GD is grads over all data. So technically grads over batch is SGD as well.

Comment: @danyfang Yes that's exactly what I meant, I wanted to speed up by feeding a batch. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you only have one computation graph and in one session there can be only one graph, I think you will have to do it in the way you posted, e.g. run it one by one. Any batch size bigger than 1 won't give you the gradient w.r.t each sample.

Answer (score 0):

Although, there is an 'aggregation_method' parameter in tf.gradients, it is not easy to get the individual gradients.

```
aggregation_method: Specifies the method used to combine gradient terms.
```

Please see these threads:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15760
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4897

In one of the threads(#4897), Ian Goodfellow makes the following suggestion to speed up individual gradient computation:

```
This is only pseudocode, but basic idea is:

examples = tf.split(batch)
weight_copies = [tf.identity(weights) for x in examples]
output = tf.stack(f(x, w) in zip(examples, weight_copies))
cost = cost_function(output)
per_example_gradients = tf.gradients(cost, weight_copies)
```

Comment: and what is `f` in this example?

Comment: The question is how can I use this if weights are the parameters of a neural network defined in Keras?

Comment: f is the function which maps input to output. In your case, the neural network.

Comment: but this means that I would need to give the neural network the weights each time I am evaluating it. If I have a keras model `tf_net = keras.model(tf_in, f)` that I evaluate with `tf_net(x_in)`, how can I specify the weights?